# Gerrit + LDAP: "Cannot assign user name "X" to account Y; name does not conform"

Tags: ldap, gerrit

I'm new to Gerrit. The guy that made the setup left the company and now I need to create an account for a new employee.

We're using LDAP to authenticate. It works for all registered users.

The new user should be able to login to Gerrit if he already has an account that is supplied through LDAP. Right?

But, when he tries to login, the error "`Cannot assign user name "Example Name" to account 1000054; name does not conform.`" appears.
Detail: The account number(1000054, in the example) gets increased after each unsuccessful login attempt.
Detail2: if a wrong password is entered, an error of wrong email/password is thrown.

Talking with the LDAP admin, he told that the request for the user hasn't arrived at the LDAP server.

Tried to open Gerrit DB using `java -jar bin/gerrit.war gsql`. There in nothing related to this new user in "ACCOUNTS" and "ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS" tables.

Our settings:

```
[ldap]
    server = ldap://LDAP_SERVER_IP
    accountBase = OU=Usuários Rede,OU=COMPANY,DC=COMPANY,DC=com,DC=br
    groupBase = OU=Grupos,OU=COMPANY,DC=COMPANY,DC=com,DC=br
    referral = follow
    accountPattern = (mailNickname=${username})
    groupPattern = (memberOf=${cn})
    accountFullName = cn
    accountEmailAddress = mail
    accountSshUserName = cn
    username = ldapread@COMPANY_NAME.com.br
    password = PASS
```

How can I debug what's wrong in here? The usernames in our company follow the pattern `name.surname`.

I'm really lost. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could get it to work!

What I did:

1. Stopped Gerrit (`./bin/gerrit.sh stop`)
2. Opened the database (`java -jar bin/gerrit.war gsql`)
3. Inserted new row in ACCOUNTS table (`insert into ACCOUNTS values ('2018-10-11 00:00:00.000', 'Name Surname', 'name.surname@company.com.br', 'N', 'NULL', 1000052);`)
4. Inserted two new rows in ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS table referencing the new user id (`insert into ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS values ('1000052', 'name.surname@company.com.br', 'NULL', 'gerrit:name.surname');` and `insert into ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS values ('1000052', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'username:name.surname');`)
5. Started Gerrit again (`./bin/gerrit.sh start`)

If anyone can explain what happened here... Please!

Answer (score 0):

I compared our settings with yours and I think something is missing in the accountPattern and groupPattern. This is our settings:

```
accountPattern = (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=${username}))
groupPattern = (&(objectClass=group)(cn=${groupname}))
```

The "objectClass=xxxx" clause is shown in the [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#ldap) ldap example too.

But I can't explain why it doesn't work only for new users.

Comment: After doing these changes neither I could login to Gerrit anymore. But thanks for the help anyway. Obrigado.